# Permalinks Change Broke My Website

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, digital-ocean, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a change to the settings in my permalinks section on my Wordpress site today and now all the links except for the homepage are broken.

I don't remember what my original permalink setting was and I've changed it many times to try and revert it. Sorry about that.

My website is www.californiabeardco.com

I've done a bunch of searching for a solution and following some instructions have edited my .htaccess file to say:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also updated the file /wp-includes/vars.php from this...

```
$is_apache = (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Apache') !== false || strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'LiteSpeed') !== false);
```

...to this

```
$is_apache = 1;
```

I have shared hosting (I believe) through Digital Ocean where I have one droplet.

Thank you in advance for any help, and please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Can't you undo the change and then proceed very carefully in your next attempt?

Comment: I don't remember what I changed it from, and have tried many other options now in an attempt to revert back

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't change your .htaccess file because you may compound the complexity of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a bearded gentleman, I'd love to help you if you didn't get this done. I notice everything is working on the live site, but you aren't using pretty urls.

Since you are running your own droplet, there's a good chance you need to allow WordPress to access your .htaccess file.

```
chmod -v 666 .htaccess
```

Also, I'd recommend creating an image of the droplet and changing your apache config to using the public ip as root. Then you can get this stuff working and not affect your live env.

Cheers!